# writing structures using fstream in c++

Tags: c++

Please tell me that the following line writes the address of the structure variable to the file or it writes the values of members of the structure.

```
 file_write.write((char*)&structure_data,sizeOfStructure);
```

Where file_write is fstream's object and "structure_data" is a struct having 3 members of integer datatypes. Thanks.

Comment: It takes whatever `structure_data` is, and just copies those blob of bytes to a file.  It doesn't figure out what the members are.  Also, this is the cause for thousands of SO questions that erroneously do codiing like this, where `structure_data` cannot be written to a file this way and have the file make sense.  Look up *object serialization*.

Comment: it is not writing the address, its writing the data in the structure. Now depending on the struct that might not do what you expect

Comment: `write` also takes a `char*`, so you are converting to `char*` here, which IIRC results in implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Please suggest me an effective alternative for above line.@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Ehtesham See the answer I gave.  The easiest thing is to write each member to the file using the operator `<<` for each item.

Comment: Thank you sir. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Reminder:  the compiler is allowed to add *padding* bytes between structure members (e.g. for alignment).  So, your `write` will write those padding bytes to the file as well.

Comment: The `write` is not a good idea if your members are pointers or are classes that contain pointers (such as `std::string` or `std::vector`).  A better method is to write the members individually.  Search the internet for "C++ serialization".

Answer (score 4):

This line:

`file_write.write((char*)&structure_data,sizeOfStructure);`

takes whatever `structure_data` is, and just copies those blob of bytes that makes up `structure_data` to a file.

It doesn't figure out what the members are. Also, this is the cause for thousands of SO questions that erroneously do coding like this, where `structure_data` cannot be written to a file this way and have the file contents make sense.  It is quickly discovered that the contents of the file are useless when an attempt to read back the data into a program 
is unsuccessful.

Most of the time in those scenarios `structure_data` would contain pointers, or members that are not C-layout compatible, i.e. non-POD types such as `std::string` or `std::vector`, that basically renders this technique of writing to a file like this totally useless (and invalid).

Look up object serialization such as [this link on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816037/object-serialization-in-c)